# What exactly are the approximations in Hartree-Fock?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, approximations, quantum-chemistry

I have read a book about [Hartree-Fock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) but I am not sure of that simple question.

Questions that should help me to understand are:

- Is an approximation to consider only one determinant?
- Is the product of wavefunctions an approximation?

(Besides the [Born-Oppenheimer approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation).)

Maybe mathematical illustrations of approximations would help.

Answer (score 4):

Is an approximation to consider only one determinant? In a word, **yes**. Hartree-Fock methods require that the wavefunction be as separable as possible, and this means that they are unable to describe states with higher correlations such as, say,
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2) = \frac12\left(\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)-\phi(x_1)\psi(x_2) +\chi(x_1)\xi(x_2)-\xi(x_1)\chi(x_2)\right)
$$
(where obviously $\psi$, $\phi$, $\chi$ and $\xi$ need to be orthogonal).

Once you do this approximation, you still have the problem of finding the best possible set of orbitals to describe the state you want to do, which is where the mean-field description comes in, but this isn't so much an approximation as an optimization problem: you're trying to find the Slater determinant that does the best job (out of an impossible task) to describe the true eigenstate. The different variations of Hartree-Fock correspond to different metrics for what "best" means and how you solve that optimization problem.

If you want to do an accurate description of atoms and molecules, you typically need to go beyond Hartree-Fock, and there are a [variety of methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Hartree%E2%80%93Fock) to do that, with their respective advantages and disadvantages. I think the flavour there is best captured by the [Configuration Interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_interaction) method: there, you solve the full Hartree-Fock schmock to get, say, the $|1s^2\rangle$, $|1s2s\rangle$, $|1s2p\rangle$, $\ldots$, states (Slater determinants) of helium, say, but then you would just use these as a basis: you say, well, my ground state has the form
$$
|\Psi\rangle = \alpha |1s^2\rangle+ \beta|1s2s\rangle+\gamma|1s2p\rangle + \cdots,
$$
where you expect $\alpha$ to carry most of the population, but with important corrections coming from $\beta$, $\gamma$, and so on. Other post-Hartree-Fock methods are vaguely similar, such as [MCTDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-configuration_time-dependent_Hartree), while others like [coupled cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupled_cluster) take a harder tack into tougher mathematics.

For most vanilla-flavour situations, you do need the above methods, but they're typically only solving for small corrections to the state, with the bulk of the population generally well described by a single determinant. However, in some cases ([example](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/qua.560140506)) this can completely break down, and you can have situations where two (or three, or ten) determinants contribute significantly to the state, and there is no way to reduce that complexity.

Comment: I am not sure about the sense you are using Correlation in the beginning, can you explain it only a bit? I do not see exactly why that would be an approximation

Comment: Anyway, the second question is greatly answered (thanks) but, i am not sure if you answer the first question: Is to propose wavefunction as a product of monoelectronic wavefunctions an approximation?

Answer (score 0):

The product form or sum of products is the primary HF approximation. The true wave function should reflect the fact that each constituent is correlated with every other comstituent. HF accommodates this via a mean field approach which cannot reflect true two-body and higher correlations.